# Facing some issues while working with SwiftUI (See Details)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a screen in SwiftUI. In that I'm facing some issues, Like:

1. `NavigationButton` is not working in the `navigationBarItems`.
2. View are not starting from top of the screen always aligned at the centre of the screen.

Code:

```
struct ContactDetailView : View {

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        ContactDetailHeaderView()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .frame(height: UIDevice.screenWidth*0.8)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [AppColors.white, AppColors.themeGreen.opacity(0.6)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom), cornerRadius: 0)

        ContactDetailRow(title: "Mobile", description: "+91 1248932410") //View for creating row
        ContactDetailRow(title: "Email", description: "pramod@yopmail.com") //View for creating row
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            NavigationButton(destination: AddContactView()) {
                Text("Edit")
                    .font(AppFonts.Regular.withSize(17.0))
                    .foregroundColor(AppColors.themeGreen)
            }
    )
 }
}
```

If any one got some idea in that please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: And you forgot to add code .in que !!

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya code added.

Comment: End of the VStack add Spacer() it will move up your views. And You need add NavigationView  before VStack (not sure on this point)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya not working for me.

Comment: Your view not moved up? or navigation button not working ?

Comment: You may need to use .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

Comment: Use PresentationButton instead of navigation button in navigation bar items.

Comment: @ShaafiShovon But I wanna navigate to another screen, not present.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya after adding .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)  content moved up, but navigation button not working.

Answer (score 0):

By using a ScrollView, it will start from the top of the screen.